# Inno UninstallRun How To get global variable by executing

Tags: inno-setup

My target is to read a registry entry at [UninstallRun].

The issue is, if Inno Setup is running in an install process the Function GetRegistryVar() is called here ? It should be called when the UnInstall process is running. If I start the UnInstall process the Function GetRegistryVar() will not called here ? Only the CurUninstallStepChanged() and PGetRegistryVal(). So I can't receive my global variable gStrPrnName ?

```
[UninstallRun]
Filename: "{#dInst64bitDir}\{#dUnInstDrvExeName}"; Parameters: "-f {code:GetGlobalRegistryVar}"; WorkingDir: "{#dInst64bitDir}"; Flags: runhidden runascurrentuser;

[Code]
var
  gStrPrnName: string;

function GetGlobalRegistryVar(Value: string): string;
begin
  Result := gStrPrnName;
end;

procedure CurUninstallStepChanged(CurUninstallStep: TUninstallStep);
  begin
    case CurUninstallStep of
    usUninstall:
      begin
      // ...insert code to perform pre-uninstall tasks here...
      PGetRegistryVal(gStrPrnName);
      end;
    usPostUninstall:
      begin
      // ...insert code to perform post-uninstall tasks here...
      end;
  end;
end;


function PGetRegistryVal(Value: String): String;
var
  strPrnName: string;
  i: Integer;
begin

     for i:=0 to 2 do
   begin
      if RegQueryStringValue(HKLM, 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\GetDevice_1', 'Name', strPrnName) then
        Result := strPrnName;
      if RegQueryStringValue(HKLM, 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\GetDevice_2', 'Name', strPrnName) then
        Result := strPrnName;
     ...
   end;
end;
```

Has somebody a solution for this issue ?

Thanks

Comment: That's because the `[UninstallRun]` section parameters are expanded at installation time (when the setup is writing uninstall log) and you are having your global variable empty at that time. If you need to get that reg. value at uninstallation time, you'll need to stop using `[UninstallRun]` section and run that app. manually from `[Code]`.

Comment: For those who take installation scripting serious I add, that you should avoid using global variables like in this script.